# Macbook doesn’t get into sleep mode if I don’t close the cover?

Tags: mac, screen-lock

I worked yesterday with MacBook and went to bed with the cover open.

When I woke up, the battery died to 0% and I couldn’t turn it on until I plug in the power.

So, MacBook gets into sleep mode only with the cover closed?
Like, it gets into only Lock Screen mode but is still processing taking up the battery when the cover is open?

- It’s MacBook Air M1(2020) with Mac OS Ventura, the newest version.
- Nothing was plugged into my Mac.
- The battery lever was approximately 25%.
- I wasn’t using a special app. Only Safari, Chrome, Sticky Notes, Miro(an endless memo note app). These were pretty much all.

Comment: Which exact model and year of MacBook is this? What OS are you running? Is anything plugged into the Mac? What was the battery level when you went to bed? 
Sleep mode can be prevented by certain processes. What apps were you running?

Comment: Sorry for vague detail! It’s MacBook Air M1(2020) with Mac OS Ventura, the newest version. Nothing was plugged into my Mac. The battery lever was approximately 25%? I wasn’t using a special app. Only Safari, Chrome, Sticky Notes, Miro(an endless memo note app). These are pretty much all.

Comment: "It's always Chrome."